# How to use HTTPClient from within EJB in TomEE

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-tomee, jca

I have an EJB3 bean that needs to GET or POST from multiple HTTP servers. I have read the documentation on writing JCA adapters, as well as the documentation on Apache HTTPComponents, specifically the managed connections, managed connection factories, etc. that HTTPClient offers.

I note that the documentation for [BasicHttpClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.html) says to use it, rather than [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) "Inside of an EJB Container."  It is unclear whether "Inside of an EJB Container" refers to user code in an EJB to be run in a container, or to the container's own implementation code (e.g. something you might put in a JCA adapter.

I'm still a little unclear, architecturally, how to handle the task to take maximum advantage of the servics offered by the container. Thus far, my choices seem to be:

1. From within the EJB, create a new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager, and then create a client, like so:

   ```
       BasicHttpClientConnectionManager cxMgr = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager()
       HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cxMgr).build()
   ```

   This would, I believe, result in no connection pooling, but rather EJB instance pooling, which probably wouldn't be all that performant since the EJB container has no way of knowing which bean instance is holding an active connection to which remote HTTP server.
2. Write a (fairly minimal) JCA adapter that wraps the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager, and then, within the EJB, grab that adapter with a @Resource annotation and use it to build the HTTPClient
3. Write a JCA adapter that manages a pool of HTTPClients and hands those out when needed.

I am unclear on which approach I should take, or on whether or not I'm ignoring some sort of HTTP Connection management service that's already built into the container (in this case, TomEE plus). How should I do this?

Comment: I have used the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager directly within an EJB (no JCA adapter), but that was a Singleton (we're using ejb-3.1) and has a fairly fixed number of connections

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple: none of those options match. The particular answer depends on whether remote side of your HTTP connection is a single resource or not.

If it's a single logical resource, then JCA matches best. Still, you should hardly avoid any references to it's HTTP nature in your adapter: design a proper logical interface for your remote system and then implement a resource adapter upon that interface. Your clients request the data they need and then receive it not as HTML strings, but as ready-to-use Java beans. You will be able to utilize much of advantages provided by EJB container without it's requirements violation.

If you need an entry point to access unspecified number of external services (HTML pages search indexing might be this kind of job), then things get tricky. JCA is not intended to be used for that kind of things, but it suites them quite for sure: I am maintaining TCP SocketConnector project which does almost the same and everything works like a charm. EJB won't fit here: stateless beans pooling is hard to control, singletons will require you to write non-blocking pooling implementation yourself and statefuls are, well, kind of single-threaded.

There's also an extra option: while JCA will be easier to integrate to your existing Java EE environment, it might be hard to implement a resource adapter from scratch if you're doing it for the first time. An external HTTP querying tool which is connected with a JMS queue might come in handy here. JMS will make it easier to balance workload, but it removes any interactivity and may slow the whole chain down.

P.S. For the third option of your original question: there's no need to implement pooling in JCA as container already maintains connections pool for all resource adapter instances by default. Just keep a single HTTP Client connection per JCA's ManagedConnection and everything will work out-of-the-box.